# How to hide the Token model from rest_framework.authtoken in django admin panel

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-rest-framework, django-admin, token

I tried to solve the problem using this two methods

```
from rest_framework.authtoken.models import Token
admin.site.unregister(Token)
-----
from rest_framework.authtoken.models import TokenProxy 
admin.site.unregister(TokenProxy)
```

But the response is a mistake that says
"The model Token is not registered"

Answer (score 2):

I faced the same problem with `Django==4.0.4` and `djangorestframework==3.13.1`. I had new Django project with DRF and even though I did not register the model `Token` it was showing up on the admin site.

When I click the `Token` link in the admin, it was redirect me to `/admin/authtoken/tokenproxy/`. So, instead of the `Token` model, unregister the `TokenProxy` model from admin site;

```
from rest_framework.authtoken.models import TokenProxy

admin.site.unregister(TokenProxy)
```

This solved my problem.

Answer (score -2):

You have to remove rest_framework.authtoken from INSTALLED_APPS

Comment: This disables the token authentication feature, which was not the intention of the original question.